# Is "the validity of the argument" correct?

Tags: articles, definite-article

[In this manual](https://crunchprep.com/gre-analytical-writing-guide) I've met a sentence:

> 5. Conclusion: Give final evaluation of the validity of the argument.

During my classes, I was told that the double usage of *the* in structures like *A of B* is prohibited.
Also, I've read a manual about the usage of articles, but I don't remember any information regarding this issue.

Is the quoted sentence correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would say:

> 5. Conclusion: Give **a** final evaluation of the validity of the argument.

It just sounds a bit odd to me to not have an article before *final evaluation* there but that might be due to location/cultural differences.

As for your question about the double usage of *the*, it's absolutely fine. There is nothing wrong with the phrase *the validity of the argument* and I have never heard of such a rule on the number of articles you can use in a phrase. Is it possible that you misunderstood? What did your teacher say you should do to avoid such usage? If you have any notes from the class about the rule, can you add them to your question?

Comment: It was during a class, when he said that "the state of the flora" is incorrect. We were describing a condition of some island while preparing for the essay part of IELTS. However, yes, he didn't say it explicitly, that _the A of the B_ is incorrect in general.