# Punctuation and articles check

Tags: articles, punctuation

When asking [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145182/is-the-validity-of-the-argument-correct) question, I used three following sentences:

> In this manual I've met a sentence:
>
> During my classes, I was told that the double usage of *the* in structures like *A of B* is prohibited.
>
> Also, I've read a manual about the usage of articles, but I don't remember any information regarding this issue.

Are punctuation and articles in these sentences correct?
(I want to know whether my basics are right. Preparing for GRE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence one. Don't use met. Use **encountered**. It does NOT require a comma. In such a short sentence a comma is redundant and even unhelpful.

Sentence two. Grammar is fine.

Sentence three. The second comma is unnecessary. Advice to include the second comma is likely to come from American English users. You'd best check with your examination board about use of commas when joining independent clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Your punctuation and articles are mostly fine. In the first sentence, it's better to add a comma between *In this manual* and *I've met a sentence*. Also, a native speaker would not say that they *met* a sentence. They would say:

> In this manual, I **saw** the sentence
>
> In this manual, I **read** the sentence

and so on.